# Get text between two character JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex, match

I want to get all text between two character Example

```
<div class="text-center">
                <a href="/Users/Users/EditUser?UserId={userId}" title=@Resource.EditTlp data-userRole="{userRole}">
                    <span class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></span>
                </a>

                <a href="/Users/Users/DeleteUser?UserId={userId}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')" title=@Resource.DeleteTlp>
                    <span class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
```

i have this html in a variable and i need the all texts in a array between the brackets **"{}"**

expected result is:

1.{userId}

2.{userRole}

3.{userId}

in a list. I tried with `actualHtml.match(/\{(.*)\}/g)`

but result getting is wrong it taking first bracket and last bracket 
i got the result is  `{userId}" title=@Resource.EditTlp data-userRole="{userRole}`

Comment: `html.match(/\{([^}]+)\}/)`  You want to match on anything *except* a closing bracket

Comment: **Worked!** Huge thanks @Taplar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer from **Talpar**

`html.match(/\{([^}]+)\}/)` that's all